# Broken authentication after upgrading from symfony 5.2 to 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, ldap, basic-authentication

I have had a working HTTP Basic LDAP authentication, which is not functional any more. Previously I received a log like this:

```
[2022-02-18T17:43:22.169939+01:00] request.INFO: Matched route "app_szerszamnyilvantarto_folap". {"route":"app_szerszamnyilvantarto_folap","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_szersza
mnyilvantarto_folap","_controller":"App\\Controller\\SzerszamNyilvantarto::FoLap"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/SzerszamNyilvantarto","method":"GET"} []
[2022-02-18T17:43:22.186776+01:00] security.INFO: Basic authentication Authorization header found for user. {"username":"kralg"} []
```

After upgrade to 5.4 I am having this:

```
[2022-02-19T19:09:14.027697+01:00] request.INFO: Matched route "app_szerszamnyilvantarto_folap". {"route":"app_szerszamnyilvantarto_folap","route_parameters":{"_route":"app_szersza
mnyilvantarto_folap","_controller":"App\\Controller\\SzerszamNyilvantarto::FoLap"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/SzerszamNyilvantarto","method":"GET"} []
[2022-02-19T19:09:14.032640+01:00] security.DEBUG: Checking for authenticator support. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticators":1} []
[2022-02-19T19:09:14.032798+01:00] security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Ldap\\Security\\LdapAuthenticator
"} []
[2022-02-19T19:09:14.032902+01:00] security.DEBUG: Authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Ldap\\Security\\LdapAuth
enticator"} []
[2022-02-19T19:09:14.052965+01:00] php.CRITICAL: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getUsername() on null {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function g
etUsername() on null at /var/...../src/Controller/SzerszamNyilvantarto.php:30)"} []
```

To my highest surprise it not only fails, but looks like it tries to load the page without authentication!

Questions:

1. Anyone any idea how I could learn about the concept of authenticators supporting a request? Isn't it me deciding what authenticator to use in the config file?
2. Is there any way to get further debug information what and why is happening? I tried checking around all the logs, but nothing takes me closer to the solution.

After reading through several times the available security-bundle pages at symfony.com, I ended up thinking that my previous configuration needs no change, it should just work.

Any hints or clues are greatly appreciated.

config/packages/security.yaml:

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    providers:
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }
        app_user_provider:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider
        my_ldap:
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn: dc=<myserver>,dc=hu
                search_dn: null
                search_password: null
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
                uid_key: uid
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
             provider: my_ldap
             stateless: true
             http_basic_ldap:
                 realm: My Web
                 service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                 dn_string: 'uid={username},ou=People,dc=<myserver>,dc=hu'
    access_control:
```

config/services.yaml:

```
parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
        arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
        arguments:
            -   host: localhost
                port: 389
                encryption: none
                options:
                    protocol_version: 3
                    referrals: false
```

Answer (score 1):

An authenticator "supports" a request, when the request contains information that the authenticator routine can use to authenticate. Initially the browser is not sending this information, so the authenticator cannot do anything with that. Instead it needs to send a response back to the browser to tell it needs authentication headers in the request.

In my case this response was not sent back. The problem can be "fixed" by disabling the `enable_authenticator_manager` option, so the old **authentication provider** mechanism is used, instead of the new **authenticator**s. However in Symfony 6 this option **MUST** be enabled, so it is still a question how it will work there...